# Wy decimal numbers are not stored as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to save numbers in decimal data type filed formated **(10,4)**, but it's not stored as expected ie. **13850** changed to **13.0000** any help.
this is my code:

```
$c_price = $unit_price*$rate;
  $expense->c_price = number_format($c_price, 4);
  $expense->c_total = number_format($quantity*$c_price, 4);
```

Here c_price and c_total values are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the length of digits:

```
(19,4)
```

it will work.